# chaining futures with for loop containing not only futures

Tags: scala

I have a problem with chaining 2 futures together what I would like  to do is the following :

```
import scala.concurrent.{ ExecutionContext, Future } 

 def lastFiveFullNews: Future[Seq[FullNews]] = {
  for (
  seq <- getLastFiveNews;
  news <- seq;
  fullNews <- getFullNewsById(news.id) //error at this line

) yield fullNews
}
```

with the following method signatures :

```
def getLastFiveNews: Future[Seq[News]]
def getFullNewsById(id: Long): Future[FullNews]
def lastFiveFullNews: Future[Seq[FullNews]]
```

basically a FullNews is generated with a News' id.
In the Idea editor no error is reported but the play compiler says :

> type mismatch;  found   : scala.concurrent.Future[FullNews]  required:
>   scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[?]

I think this doesn't work because in the for loop there is not only scala's Futures but also a Seq. But without the Seq I dont know how to write it. Any ideas ? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you suspect, you can't mix different monads in a for-comprehension. Since you're working with `Future`s, all the lines in the for-comprehension must produce `Future`s. You can use `Future.sequence`, which will convert a `Seq[Future[...]]` to a `Future[Seq[...]]`:

```
def lastFiveFullNews: Future[Seq[FullNews]] = {
  for (
    seq <- getLastFiveNews
    fullNews <- Future.sequence(
      seq.map(news => getFullNewsById(news.id))
    )
  ) yield fullNews
}
```

Comment: You could also use `Future.traverse` combining `Future.sequence` and `Seq#map` : `Future.traverse(seq)(news => getFullNewsById(news.id))`.